# do-while loop does not remember variable in while

Tags: c

```
do{        
            float diameter;

            scanf("%f",&diameter);  
            Printf("Please input diameter");
            if(cheack1(diameter) == 0){
                Printf("Please input a valid number greater than 0");
            }else{
                circle(&area, &perimeter, diameter);
            }

            int cheack = cheack1(diameter);
}while(cheack == 1);
```

I am having a problem with my do-while loop. As you can see i have already declared the

`int cheack = cheack1(diameter);`   the `cheack1(diameter);` cheacks if my input is correct and returns 1 if it is correct.

But my error is :

`p7t5.c: In function ‘main’:
p7t5.c:87:11: error: ‘cheack’ undeclared (first use in this function)`

Seems to be the `while(cheack == 1);` is not remembering the `cheack`inside the do-while loop.

Comment: while condition is out of do {} scope, not sub scope.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try declaring it outside the loop like this- 
REASON- its scope is block scope. Thats why its showing error.

```
int cheack;
do{        
            float diameter;

            scanf("%f",&diameter);  
            Printf("Please input diameter");
            if(cheack1(diameter) == 0){
                Printf("Please input a valid number greater than 0");
            }else{
                circle(&area, &perimeter, diameter);
            }

            cheack = cheack1(diameter);
}while(cheack == 1);
```

Answer (score 5):

Scope of local variable will be finished and variable will be destroyed at first closing `}` bracket.This variable is on stack and will not remain in memory as soon as scope will be finished.You need to define `cheack` out of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You have declared `cheack` inside do while loop.So it is visible within `do...while` loop and not outside of `do...while` loop.
So declare cheack outside `do...while` loop and then use it.

```
int cheack=0;
do{        
        cheack = cheack1(diameter);

   }while(cheack == 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have declared `cheack` inside the body of `do-while` loop, it's scope is within that body itself. To remove the error, declare `cheack` before entering the `do-while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong control structure, a `for` loop would be more appropriate:

```
for (int cheack = 1; cheack == 1;  cheack = cheack1(diameter)) {
   ...
}
```

has the local variable at the right level and is much clearer to the reader.

If you need the update inside the block do

```
for (int cheack = 1; cheack == 1;  ) {
   ...
   cheack = cheack1(diameter);
}
```

(And the compiler might very well optimize that to a form with the check of the condition at the very end, but doing that yourself would be premature optimization.)

Answer (score 1):

Of course you don't need `cheack` variable:

```
do{        
            float diameter;

            scanf("%f",&diameter);  
            Printf("Please input diameter");
            if(cheack1(diameter) == 0){
                Printf("Please input a valid number greater than 0");
            }else{
                circle(&area, &perimeter, diameter);
            }
}while(cheack1(diameter) == 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
do{        
        float diameter;

        scanf("%f",&diameter);  
        Printf("Please input diameter");
        if(cheack1(diameter) == 0){
            Printf("Please input a valid number greater than 0");
        }else{
            circle(&area, &perimeter, diameter);
        }

        int cheack = cheack1(diameter); /*declare this integer before the 'do.while' loop begins*/
} while(cheack == 1);
```

I changed it to this:

```
int cheack = cheack1(diameter); /*Now the integer is declared before the do-while loop begins*/

 do{        
        float diameter;

        scanf("%f",&diameter);  
        Printf("Please input diameter");
        if(cheack1(diameter) == 0){
            Printf("Please input a valid number greater than 0");
        }else{
            circle(&area, &perimeter, diameter);
        }


} while(cheack == 1);
```

But be sure that your other variables have been declared BEFORE calling this loop otherwise they exist only inside the loop and will be gone after the first loop/run.